# facebook javascript SDK return empty page after prompt for FB login

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk

I have created my first Facebook app, which allow posting updates on my page. The version of my facebook App is v2.4.  I then created a test web page with ASP.NET and use Facebook Javascript SDK to try posting a test update on my page.  It opened a prompt for login and redirect to an empty popup page after I clicked login.
The followings are the codes I used:

```
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
            FB.init({
                appId: '[my-app-id]',
                xfbml: true,
                version: 'v2.4'
            });
        };

        (function (d, s, id) {
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) { return; }
            js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

        function myFacebookLogin() {
            FB.login(function () {

                FB.api('/114690815550304/feed', 'post', { message: 'Hello, world!' });
            }, { scope: 'publish_actions' });
        }

    </script>

<div>
<asp:Button ID="PostButton" CssClass="buttonM1 bGreen" runat="server" Text="Post To Facebook Page" OnClientClick="myFacebookLogin();" />
</div>

</body>
```

Would anyone tell me what's wrong with it?
My facebook App does work on Graph API 2.0 and did successfully post an update on my page through Graph API.
The testing web page I created is also a Https, and is updated into my Facebook App's site URL setting.

Thanks in advance for any help.